# Display the elemnt of the queue

Tags: java, queue

I have  some issues to display the elements of the queue list in java with out displayed from the add method . I need to print the even numbers in the queue list

```
package ru.vsu.cs.course1;

public class SimpleLinkedListQueue2<T> implements SimpleQueue<T> {

    private class ListNode<T> {
        public T value;
        public ListNode<T> next;

        public ListNode(T value, ListNode<T> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private ListNode<T> head = null;
    private ListNode<T> tail = null;

    private int count = 0;


    @Override
    public void add(T value) {
        ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<>(value, null);
        if (count > 0) {
            tail.next = newNode;
        } else {
            head = newNode;
        }
        tail = newNode;
        count++;
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    @Override
    public T remove() throws Exception {
        if (count == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Queue is empty");
        }
        T value = head.value;
        head = head.next;
        count--;
        if (count == 0) {
            tail = null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public T element() throws Exception {
        if (count == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Queue is empty");
        }
        return head.value;
    }


public class main {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleLinkedListQueue2<Integer> queue2=new SimpleLinkedListQueue2<Integer>();
        queue2.add(67);
        queue2.add(54);
        queue2.add(75);
        queue2.add(100);
        System.out.println("--------------");


    }
}
driver code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the `ListNode` class should be `static`, so go ahead and add that keyword.

Next, the best way to add support for displaying the elements of the queue, is to make the class implement [`Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). That way the caller can iterate the elements and decide what to do with them, e.g. simply display them, or something more complex.

```java
class SimpleLinkedListQueue2<T> implements SimpleQueue<T>, Iterable<T> {

    . . .

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<>() {
            private ListNode<T> next = head;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return next != null;
            }
            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (next == null)
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                T value = next.value;
                next = next.next;
                return value;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
SimpleLinkedListQueue2<Integer> queue2=new SimpleLinkedListQueue2<>();
queue2.add(67);
queue2.add(54);
queue2.add(75);
queue2.add(100);

// Print even values
for (int value : queue2) // <== Possible because it is Iterable
    if (value % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println(value);
```

*Output*

```
54
100
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Andreas is the preferred and recommended solution. However, if you are not allowed to update `SimpleLinkedListQueue2<T>` the following code will mark out the even entries. The only hiccup will be the extra `println` during `add` and `remove` operations. **Beware,** this implementation is written only for laughs and must NEVER be used in the wild.

```
public static void printEven(SimpleLinkedListQueue2<Integer> queue) throws Exception {

    SimpleLinkedListQueue2<Integer> tempQ = new SimpleLinkedListQueue2<Integer>();
    while (true) {
        try {
            queue.element();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
        Integer tempInt = queue.remove();
        if (tempInt%2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("even: " + tempInt.toString());
        }
        tempQ.add(tempInt);
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            tempQ.element();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
        queue.add(tempQ.remove());
    }
}
```

The logic here is pop the head, read and evaluate if it is even, push it into a temporary queue, then restore the original queue. The output will be:

```
67
54
75
100
--------------
67
even: 54
54
75
even: 100
100
67
54
75
100
```